# bash: don't understand the difference between these two methods - should be the same, but isn't...?

Tags: bash, menu, dialog, tr

I have a file:`$ cat /tmp/test.txt

     1 "African Countries AFR"
     2 "Albania AL"
     3 "Arab Countries ARB"
     4 "Austria AT"`

I'm trying to learn this linux-utility, but this is obviously wrong:

```
$ dialog --menu "Choose toppings:" 35 35 5 $(cat /tmp/test.txt)

                                  │ │    1          "African      │ │  
                                  │ │    Countries  AFR"          │ │  
                                  │ │    2          "Albania      │ │  
                                  │ │    AL"        3             │ │  
                                  │ │    "Arab      Countries     │ │  
                                  │ │    ARB"       4             │ │  
                                  │ │    "Austria   AT"           │ │
```

So I thought I should try without the linebreak:

```
$ dialog --menu "Choose toppings:" 35 35 5 $(cat /tmp/test.txt | tr -d '\n')
```

But that is also wrong (same result as above)! After struggling a lot with it, I decided to try manually adding the contents and entering them as arguments on the command line:

```
$ cat /tmp/test.txt | tr -d '\n'
     1 "African Countries AFR"     2 "Albania AL"     3 "Arab Countries ARB"     4 "Austria AT"
```

So here's the command line and the result:

```
$ dialog --menu "Choose toppings:" 30 35 5   1 "African Countries AFR"     2 "Albania AL"     3 "Arab Countries ARB"     4 "Austria AT"

                                  │ │  1  African Countries AFR   │ │  
                                  │ │  2  Albania AL              │ │  
                                  │ │  3  Arab Countries ARB      │ │  
                                  │ │  4  Austria AT              │ │
```

And suddenly the result is CORRECT - why?

And how do I modify the line "dialog --menu "Choose toppings:" 35 35 5 $(cat /tmp/test.txt | tr -d '\n')" so it gives the correct result?

Comment: When you use `$(somecommand)` (and don't put double-quotes around it), the result is split into *words*, not lines. It doesn't even pay attention to quotes, it just breaks it up by whitespace. It'll also try to expand anything that looks like a filename wildcard into a list of matching files!

Comment: @Gordon: That's great, thanks. But from the last line (' dialog --menu "Choose toppings:" 30 35 5   1 "African Countries AFR"     2 "Albania AL"     3 "Arab Countries ARB"     4 "Austria AT" '), which works - the result is also words - not lines... Why is there a difference between the words I directly entered on the command line and the words, coming as a result of $(cat /tmp/test.txt), where I also removed the linebreaks? Also about "It'll also try to expand anything that looks like a filename wildcard into a list of matching files!" : There's nothing to expand here, as I see it, right?

Comment: The shell parses quotes before expanding things like `$( )`. If the quotes are part of the actual command line, the shell recognizes them and, for example, treats `"Albania AL"` as indicating that `Albania AL` is just a single "word" that happens to contain a space. But if the `$( )` produces  `"Albania AL"`, by the time it's part of the command it's too late for the quotes to have their intended effect; they're just treated as normal characters, so the string gets split into two words,  `"Albania` and  `AL"`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson : Ok, understood, thanks a lot... You actually answered the main question or concern for me in a comment. I think I understand the behaviour now, from your last comment. So as I see it, there's no other solution than to use the "--file" option which "peak" (user) came up with... Thanks a lot to both you and peak, I had struggled for some hours with this a couldn't figure out the solution myself. Thanks both, I'm grateful for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the --file option:

```
dialog --menu "Choose toppings:" 35 35 5 --file /tmp/test.txt
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, it's also a solution - much appreciated, but it's not really the full explanation, is it? I still don't really understand what's the difference between entering that stuff directly on the command line as arguments - vs $(cat ... somestuff)? And why is there a difference between (1) dialog --menu "Choose toppings:" 35 35 5 "$(cat /tmp/test.txt | tr -d '\n')" and (2) dialog --menu "Choose toppings:" 35 35 5 $(cat /tmp/test.txt | tr -d '\n')  - neither produces the correct result! Why? And is it possible to produce the correct result without the "--file"-option? Appreciate your help..

Comment: `dialog` reads its arguments directly. It's as simple as that. Rather silly as far as I can see but there it is.

Comment: Cool, marked as answered - because I think this seems to be the only possible solution (usually there are several methods to solve a linux/bash/shell-problem, but here I only see this method, thanks - also to gordonDavisson - I couldn't see this solution and understand the problem before asking here)...

Answer (score 1):

As you say, there's usually another way ...

```
cat << EOF > magic
dialog --menu "Choose toppings:" 35 35 5 $(test.txt | tr '\n' ' ')
EOF

. magic
```

Or if you're willing to use `eval`:

```
eval $(cat << EOF
dialog --menu "Choose toppings:" 35 35 5 $(test.txt | tr '\n' ' ')
EOF
```

)

Comment: Nice to see another method/solution. There isn't so much explanation here, but I'm guessing that the difference - and why it works, is that the shell first evaluates $(test.txt | ...) and hereafter it's like if I had typed everything exactly as on the command-line... In the original case (as Gordon D wrote), double quotes were treated as normal characters, so the string gets split into two words, "Albania and AL" etc - which doesn't work as intented... So cool - and thanks for the extra solution to set things into another perspective!